# Set the d attribute on path element

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-progressindicator

I'm trying to change the value of the d attribute below:

```
<path class="slds-progress-ring__path" id="slds-progress-ring-path-1" d="M 1 0 A 1 1 0 0 0 1 -2.4492935982947064e-16 L 0 0"></path>
```

I tried to change it with the setAttribute:

```
this.template.querySelector('#slds-progress-ring-path-1').setAttribute('d','M 1 0 A 1 1 0 0 0 -0.8090169943749475 -0.587785252292473 L 0 0');
```

And also by directly changing it:

```
this.template.querySelector('#slds-progress-ring-path-1').d = 'M 1 0 A 1 1 0 0 0 -0.8090169943749475 -0.587785252292473 L 0 0';
```

But got the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ... of null

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Don’t use ID selectors with querySelector. The IDs that you define in
>   HTML templates may be transformed into globally unique values when the
>   template is rendered. If you use an ID selector in JavaScript, it
>   won’t match the transformed ID.

You can add a data attribute and query on it

Example:

**Html**

```
<path class="slds-progress-ring__path" data-id="myid" ......
```

**JS**

```
this.template.querySelector('path[data-id=myid]').setAttribute("d", "your value");
```